# What, if any, design patterns are useful in implementing user based, record level permissions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

I'm implementing a web application using ASP.NET MVC and the Entity Framework using the Repository pattern for data access.  This application will have several unrelated users creating objects.  Each user should have access only to their own objects.

**Are there any patterns, or in-built EF functionality, that provide a method for ensuring that a user has access only to their own records?**

I'm currently thinking of adding an *owner* field to all private domain objects and implementing a class that all queries to the DB must pass through.  This class will determine if the domain object being queried is private.  If so, this class will append a filter on *owner* to the query.  Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: The problem is, user association is usually considered *meta*data, not data.  You can keep the data together, but how do you differentiate between a table that all users need access to, and a table that has only user-specific data?  If you need a mechanism like that, it's usually something you have to custom build.

Comment: I was thinking of having those domain objects that are private implement an IPrivateData interface which also defines the OwnerId field.  If a domain object does not implement that interface, it's public.

Comment: Well that makes sense; but I don't think you're going to find a pattern for that, as it seems rather business-case specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of your question is very close to the description of the [*Repository Pattern*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). This approach can be used to address the record-by-record access issue by forcing insertions of user-specific filters.

This approach decouples your client business logic from the implementation of row-based security: if you later decide to change the way that you *implement* your record-by-record access, all you need to modify is your repository implementation. The clients will not even need to recompile.

EF defines a repository for all your business entities as a partial class. You can add an interface on top of it (in a separate file), and implement the methods of your repository using EF-generated methods:

```
IMyRepository {
    IQueryable<ClientOrder> Orders;
    IQueryable<ServiceIssue> Issues;
}

// The other part of MyRepository is EF-generated.
// Assume that EF provides properties these properties:
// - ObjectSet<ClientOrder> AllOrders 
// - ObjectSet<ServiceIssue> AllIssues 
public partial SecureRepository : IMyRepository {
    private readonly Guid userId;
    public SecureRepository(Guid userId) : this() {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public IQueryable<ClientOrder> Orders {
        get {
            return AllOrders.Where(ord => ord.UserId == userId);
        }
    }
    public IQueryable<ServiceIssue> Issues {
        get {
            return AllIssues.Where(csi => csi.UserId == userId);
        }
    }
}
```

You can add methods for writing that would set `UserId` on orders and issues before saving them to the database.

Comment: Can, and should, the record-by-record access logic be decoupled from the repositories?  Is it reasonable to have each individual repository concerned with record-by-record access or can some third party manage this for all repositories?

Comment: @tQuarella I added an oversimplified code example of how I would implement it using EF. If the business code interacts with `IMyRepository`, the fact that the data is pre-filtered is hidden from the business logic.